# Next.JS Deploy to Github Pages

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Trying to deploy my Next.JS project to Github Pages. I am running into this issue regarding dynamic API routes and not sure how to proceed.

When I was trying to deploy, it gave me an error about needing to add an export line to my next.config.js file. I modified the code to the following below, and resolved the error.

```
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Upon making this change, all my API routes now get an error whenever I try to configure it on Github pages (or run npm run build).

All the ones that take search Params return this error upon trying to build:

```
 Error: Page with `dynamic = "error"` couldn't be rendered statically because it used `nextUrl.searchParams`.
```

How do I resolve this so I can get my code up and running? I need these API routes for my software to work.